# If condition failing to evaluate to true when searching a list to see if it contains a value

Tags: java, groovy

I've written some code in Java that checks to see if a list of strings contains a value, and it works perfectly. But the problem comes when I try to run this same code in Groovy.

This is the code I'm running in Groovy:

```
static void main(string args[]){    

int count =0;

         String needle = "UAN: 123";

        for(int i =0; i<result.size(); i++) {

            List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println(result.get(i));
        }

        for(int i =0; i<result.size(); i++){
            List<String> text=new ArrayList<>();

            text.add(result.get(i)+"");
            log.info text

            for (int j=0; j<text.size(); j++){         

            if(text.get(j).contains(needle)){
                System.out.println("FOUND");
                log.info "FOUND"
                count = j;

                System.out.println("THIS IS IT: " + text.get(count));
                log.info text.get(count)   

            } }
}
```

It's failing at the `if` condition which I don't understand why because it works perfectly in Java.

NOTE: This list contains 2 other lists within it, and so I've used a `for` loop to access the inner list and check if the inner list contains the desired value.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

This is where it fails:

```
for(int i =0; i<result.size(); i++){
                List<String> text=new ArrayList<>();

                text.add(result.get(i)+"");
                log.info text

                for (int j=0; j<text.size(); j++){         

                if(text.get(j).contains(needle)){
                    System.out.println("FOUND");
                    log.info "FOUND"
                    count = j;

                    System.out.println("THIS IS IT: " + text.get(count));
                    log.info text.get(count)   

                } }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Well not an error per say, but the if condition is failing which means it can't find the value im looking for i.e. uan:123 even though when i print the elements of the list "text" i can see that value Note, it's a list that contains a list

Answer (score 0):

It's a tad unclear from your question what it is that you actually want to do, but to search a list of strings in groovy you can do something like:

```
def needle = "UAN: 123"
def result = ["alice", "why", "some text UAN: 123 xx", "is", "a", "writing", "desk"]
def found  = result.find { it.contains(needle) }
println found
```

which prints:

```
some text UAN: 123 xx
```

if you want both the index and the value you can for example do:

```
def needle = "UAN: 123"
def result = ["alice", "why", "some text UAN: 123 xx", "is", "a", "writing", "desk"]
def (index, found) = result.indexed().findResult { i, s -> 
  s.contains(needle) ? [i, s] : null
}
println "found '${found}' at index ${index}"
```

which prints:

```
found 'some text UAN: 123 xx' at index 2
```

in general, if all you want to do is to traverse through some collection and either find a value or somehow transform each value, you would normally not have to do `for` loops in groovy but rather use groovy extension methods like [list.find {}](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)), [map.find {}](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)), [list.collect {}](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)), etc.

The groovy documentation chapter [iterating on a list](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_iterating_on_a_list) might be a good place to start.

[ Additional solution after clarifying comments below ]

The below uses a nested list structure and finds both the item and the indexes it was found at:

```
def needle = "UAN: 123"
def result = [ ["alice", "why"],
               ["is", "a", "raven"], 
               ["like", "some text UAN: 123 xx", "a"],
               ["writing", "desk"]]


def (outerIndex, innerIndex, found) = result.indexed().findResult { i, inner -> 
  inner.indexed().findResult { j, s -> 
    s.contains(needle) ? [i, j, s] : null
  }
}

println "value '$found' found at outer index $outerIndex and inner index $innerIndex"
```

prints:

```
value 'some text UAN: 123 xx' found at outer index 2 and inner index 1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, the only thing is, that array which you have called result is a single array, whereas I have a list which in turn contains a list, so I'm having to do a nested for loop to access that inner list and check if it contains a value

Comment: hi @Matt, do you actually need to know the index or which nested array the value is in or is it enough to know if the value can be found? Also is your data type a string array (`String[]`) or a string list (`List<String>`)?

Comment: I need to know the index in which the value exists in so I can print out the value at that index

Comment: @Matt what I'm asking is: if we can write something in groovy which finds the matching value and returns it, giving you the found value in a variable, do you still care what index it came from?

If you don't care and we are dealing with lists rather than arrays, then you can just replace `resul.xx` with `result.flatten().xx` in the above and it would work for your nested structure.

Comment: @Maias, yep, the reason being is because, that index contains other values that I've not specified in the OP, and would need to print out those values. I think the issue here is that I have a nested list

Comment: @Matt added a solution with nested structure of lists

Comment: Adding to @MatiasBjarland suggestion, you can consider findAll or collectMany if you need more than one result or you can adopt more imperative styles as well, e.g.:
```
result.eachWithIndex { inner, i -> 
  inner.eachWithIndex { s, j -> 
    if (s.contains(needle)) println "value '$s' found at outer index $i and inner index $j"
  }
}
```